# jQuery UI Autocomplete doesn't seem to work in MVC5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm creating an MVC5 app, and I have installed jQuery UI to the app through Nuget packages, it installed the version 1.11.1. Then, in my _Layout.cshtml file, I have something like this:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

Also, in my view, I have something defined like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceName, "Service", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
     <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ServiceName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "service-manual" } })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServiceName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
</div>
```

Finally, I have written some C# code, where I get some information from the database, and produce a JSON file. Then, I have a JS part, where I do some AJAX call in order to make autocomplete work. And it looks like this:

```
$("#service-manual").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetBusinessDesriptions",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                state: $("#StateID").val(),
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.item.value);
        $("#service-manual").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#service-manual").text(ui.item.value);
    }
});
```

Also not to forget to mention, I have called my script in my view like this:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
}
```

So, the point is that when I open the view, and I start typing in the label, I get suggestion from the autocomplete, but I'm not able to press the one I want and select it, simply make it appear as text inside my label.

I get the following error message, when I move my mouse (hover mouse) through the suggestions returned by the autocomplete:

> TypeError: item is undefined jquery-ui-1.11.1.js:2971

And, whenever I press a suggestion that I want, I get the following error message:

> TypeError: ui.item is undefined main.js:86

I guess there is some conflict between jQuery UI Autocomplete and the Html.EditorFor in MVC. Any idea what the problem might be, and how can I solve it?

**EDIT:**

Server side, generating JSON file:

```
    public JsonResult GetBusinessDesriptions(int state, string term)
    {
        var results = db.Users.OfType<Business>().Where(b => b.StateID == state && (term == null || b.Description.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))).Select(x => new { id = x.StateID, value = x.Description }).Distinct().Take(5).ToList();

        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: If you are using a later version of Visual Studio, put your JS code for the page into a separate file (ah, I see now you have done that). You can then breakpoint it on the select method and see what is returned. Alternatively, use a network tool like Fiddler2 (or even the F12 browser options) and see what is being returned form the server. Might be a server-side error.

Comment: P.S. Please use the bundle mechanism for your JS files to get the best performance results. modernizr and jQuery and jQuery UI can go in one bundle if they are always required.

Comment: Can you show your server code too please?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You mean the code where I create the JSON file in the controller?

Comment: Yes. Just in case the problem is there. Have you tried the other suggestions yet?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I posted that code, though, as I said I can see the suggestions, but I cannot select the one I want. I also did the thing you said, put the jquery, jquery-ui and modernizr in one bundle, and called it in the _Layout file, but now I get an error message: TypeError: u is undefined jq-jqui-modernizr:1

Comment: If you use your browser on `/Home/GetBusinessDesriptions` (please correct the spelling to `GetBusinessDescriptions` as well :) ) does it return the correct JSON?

Comment: I corrected both the spelling in the server side method and while calling the url in AJAX. But don't know why, it doesn't get the new url, it still searches for the old one: GET https://localhost:44300/Home/GetBusinessDesriptions Therefore, I change them back as they were.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie As I said once before, I don't think it has to do with the server side, I guess it is more that it cannot read the scripts properly or stuff, while I see all the suggestion for the autocomplete, but I cannot select them.

Comment: Obviously you *also* change the jQuery to fix the same spelling error (that was not a bug, just annoying) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yeah, it didn't annoy me until you told me, cause i didn't notice it before :) Anyway, any idea how to solve the problem? It still persists.